# How to change user in MySQL Command Line Client

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line

I'm using MySQL 5.5 Command Line Client tool (MySQL CLC) for Windows. When I run this tool, the first thing I'm being asked is:

```
Enter password:
```

There is no input for username. So the default user is `root`. How can I change the `root` and log in as another user?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql -u <non-root-user>` should do it. BTW, I find [mysql login-path](http://www.speedemy.com/create-mysql-login-path/) very useful in such cases.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Your command works well inside Windows Command Prompt. But inside MySQL CLC you can't run such line. The first thing you are prompted to enter is the password.

Comment: I did indeed. I'm not really that familiar with windows, moreover how MySQL is used on Windows. However, can you tell me how do you call the MySQL CLC ? I would imagine you simply have to customize the shortcut (add appropirate argument in the shortcut properties) – while it won't allow you to enter the username in a prompt, it will let you specify a different default user.

Comment: MySQL CLC is a stand-alone shell. So I simply open it like I open Windows CMD or any other software.